# Eclipse crashing and disappearing (Windows XP)

Tags: java, crash, eclipse

I have two instances of Eclipse.

**Old instance**

Few months of use. Upgraded from Helios to Juno. JRE 1.6. Recently started crashing with `Java error code -1`. So I decided to start fresh:

**New instance**

Fresh download of Juno. JRE 1.7. From the very beginning, would randomly disappear all of a sudden. No crash messages, no log entry, no process resident. Just working, working, working, *poof!* GONE! Doesn't even auto-save on crash.

**Computer Specs**

- Windows XP SP3 with latest updates
- Pentium 4
- HP Compaq Desktop

What are the probable causes? Any idea to fix this?

**UPDATE:**

Managed to find the error log. Highlights are as follows:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x6e832906, pid=3648, tid=1632
#
# JRE version: 7.0_13-b20
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (23.7-b01 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x72906]

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x02e6ac00):  VMThread [stack: 0x03160000,0x03260000] [id=1632]

Register to memory mapping:

EAX=0x00000042 is an unknown value
EBX=0x0325fb7c is an unknown value
ECX=0x30924980 is an oop
{constMethod} 
 - klass: {other class}
 - method:       0x309249a0 {method} 'equals' '(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z' in 'org/eclipse/swt/graphics/RGB'
 - exceptions:   0x30011128
EDX=0x3ffffffe is an unallocated location in the heap
ESP=0x0325fb2c is an unknown value
EBP=0x0325fb54 is an unknown value
ESI=
[error occurred during error reporting (printing register info), id 0xc0000005]

Stack: [0x03160000,0x03260000],  sp=0x0325fb2c,  free space=1022k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [jvm.dll+0x72906]
    ...
C  [MSVCR100.dll+0x5c6de]  endthreadex+0x3a
C  [MSVCR100.dll+0x5c788]  endthreadex+0xe4
C  [kernel32.dll+0xb729]  GetModuleFileNameA+0x1ba

VM_Operation (0x0d65f854): GenCollectFull, mode: safepoint, requested by thread 0x41e5b400
```

Comment: Find out what hardware is failing in that antique you have there...

Comment: As I am no longer using the antique, I don't remember how, if at all, I resolved this issue. However the antique is still in use by someone else but fortunately (or unfortunately) they don't have to use Eclipse as their job scope is different from mine.